# How to give a package as a generic parameter in Ada?

Tags: ada

I wonder what is the syntax to pass a package to a generic function. I've tried several ways without success.

for ex.:

```
generic
    with package <<SomeThing>> is <>;
    procedure forEach(g: in <<MyType>>);
```

OR

```
generic
    with package <<SomeThing>>;
    procedure forEach(g: in <<MyType>>);
```

OR

```
generic
    package <<SomeThing>>;
    procedure forEach(g: in <<MyType>>);
```

Answer (score 6):

The package must be an instance of a generic package (otherwise the compiler would not know anything about the package). The syntax is:

```
generic
   with package Foo is new Bar (<>);
procedure Foreach (G : Foo.T);
```

See the [Ada Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics#Generic_instances_of_other_generic_packages) and the examples at the end of the Reference Manual section on formal packages ([ARM 12.7](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-7.html)).